# enable click event on parallax ListView with sticky header in android

Tags: android, listview, parallax, listitem

I have implemented a listView with parallax effect with a sticky listview in android,I have used the following link for the reference and have implemented successfully this thing,But I am facing an issue on clicking the background images above the listheader,Can anybody help me to figure it out and can I find the click events of childviews of listitems

ref Link : http://javatechig.com/android/listview-header-parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android

i can't post my code as its too large to post,But if still it is needed i can post some parts.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with this click?

Comment: @ArturSzymański- i cant click childviews because of space View on it,Have you gone thru the link?will get idea.ImageView cant be clickable in that.

Comment: can you post your code where you are registering controls and want to handle click event of it? @JigarMakwana

Comment: @AnantShah - go to the link,And my issue is i cant click image in this example.

Comment: @JigarMakwana I posted answer please check and let me know if you are not getting it and this reference link is not good example of parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw reference link @Jigar Makwana posted. You will not get click event on imageView because on imageView there is **"Space control"** used inside the listview header layout, And below it that **heroimageView**(ImageView). So when you click on that header part that is not imageView it is Space widget. Even though space control cannot get click event you have to use simple **View** or use that **imageView inside listview header Layout instead of space**. But it is not proper way to implement this design & functionality. If you want to do it in proper way follow below links.

Your reference link is not good example of parallex with sticky layout.
Proper example are [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) & [Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

In that you can use CoordinatorLayout inside imageView you want click event to handle and make one layout containing your headingText and add it as listview header.That's it and works perfectly and you will never see bug again.

Code is simple:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_main_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:context="com.mazkara.user.activity.ProfileActivity">
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/heroImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </RelativeLayout>
// only if you use toolbar then specify here your toolbar start
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@color/white">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>    //toolbar end 
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stickyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#222"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Heading1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

That's it.

Comment: thanks anant,So its not possible to do in my current structure?

Comment: Yes @JigarMakwana I think this answer solve your problem so, Please accept my answer.

Comment: @Anant-indeed i couldnt solve ,but your refrence is helpful

Comment: @anant-Thanks bro,I am trying,if your help needed can u help?

Answer (score 0):

add this code after `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item " + position + 1 + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code as you do. You should pass touch event to the header Image

```
        listHeader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, mListView, false);
        mListView.addHeaderView(listHeader, null, true);
        listHeader.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            heroImageView.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

the heroImageView is the image has parallax effect.